# Replacing Micro B with USB C receptacle

Tags: usb, connector

I'm working on a circuit based on the **xcore.ai Multichannel Audio Board 1v1**. The reference uses a micro b receptacle, which is wired like this
[image: schematic]

I would like to use a USB C receptacle instead. How would that be wired while keeping signals the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For USB 2.0, in order to support power and data, you need the following signals: `GND` and `VBUS` for power (each has multiple pins, you need to connect all of them together), `Dp1`, `Dp2`, `Dn1` and `Dn2` for data (the signals are doubled to support both plug orientations, again connect both `p` and both `n` signals together) and `CC1` and `CC2` which are used to let the host know what kind of a device is connected (for your case, put a 5.1 kΩ ± 20% (or better tolerance) resistor to `GND` on each of the `CC` pins, which indicates a legacy device).

A commonly used connector that provides all of the necessary signals is a "16-pin USB Type-C female connector". Here is a couple of links with examples of such connectors, but they are very widespread and can be found at every major seller.

https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/GCT/USB4105-GF-A?qs=KUoIvG%2F9IlY%2FMLlBMpStpA%3D%3D 
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15111